# Need to write a Jquery that gets all Selectlist option values, stores them in an array and post them to an Action Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Need help to write a Jquery that gets all Selectlist option data values and stores them in an array/collection. This collection will then be sent in Ajax call to an Action Method, the action method will then return a json object/collection and I will pass this object to the function specified for onsuccess.

For some reason on the server the Action method receives no data. The array "arr" is however populated when I check the javascript with a debugger.

```
     public JsonResult GetPartPrice(int[] arr)
 {

     List<pidandprice> PidPriceList = new List<pidandprice>();

     foreach (var pid in arr.Where(x => x != null ))
     {
         var Product = context.Products.First(x => x.ProductID == pid);
         PidPriceList.Add(new pidandprice() { PartID = pid, Price = Product.ListPrice });
     }


      return Json(PidPriceList.Select(m => new {partid = m.PartID, price = m.Price}) );



}








<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = new Array();
    $('select option').each(function () {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    });






    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:50913/Customise/GetPartPrice",
        data: arr,
        success: function (data) { OnSuccess(data) }

    });




});


function OnSuccess(data) {

    alert(data.join(', '));
    //This is where to write code to append
    //all option names text with price difference

};
```

Comment: We would like to help you with a specific issue. Reading the jQuery documentation would help (jquery.com). Then try it out and ask question when you an error in your code.

Comment: I understand Jquery syntax and all functions when I look at them etc. but can't remember them just like that, I could go and waste hours picking out the proper syntax and trying the code in firebug or I could learn from a working example, which is far easier and more efficient. Stackoverflow is beautiful because it's meant to save you time and not only get you out of a problem.

Comment: I want to help you here. Here is what I do. I do not remember all the jQuery function, but a keep a cheatsheet close by to help me (http://woorkup.com/2011/05/12/jquery-visual-cheat-sheet-1-6/) cheat sheet for jQuery 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Here's a freebe : http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge/PyGey/8/

for your ajax you may want to use $.post, $.get, or $.ajax